# Socket operation on nonsocket

Tags: python, windows, winsock

I have the following class:

```
from socket import *
import select

class UdpListenerPort:
    def __init__(self, socket):
        self.socket = socket
        self.socket.setblocking(0)

    def get_data_to_dispatch(self):
        is_ready = select.select([self.socket],[],[],0.01)
        if is_ready[0]:
            return self.socket.recvfrom(0xffff)[0]
        else:
            return None
```

which is run from within a thread. When I exit from the thread, I get the following exception:

```
return self.socket.recvfrom(0xffff)[0]
socket.error: [Errno 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

How can I avoid this execption,

Thanks,

Barry

Comment: Did you call `bind` on the socket?  IIRC, WinSock will return that specific error if you call `recvfrom` on a non-bound UDP socket.

Comment: Could you devise a small self-contained example that demonstrates this, or at the very least include the complete stack trace?

Comment: yes I bind before I call __init__ for the class above. However, get_data_to_dispatch() is called from a different thread. I'm guessing the problem is that the socket is destroyed when I try to use it on either lines is_ready = select.select([self.socket],[],[],0.01) or  return self.socket.recvfrom(0xffff)[0].

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I had the thread implement as a context manager. In the exit method I had the following:

```
def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
    try:
        self.is_alive = False
        while not self.is_finished:
            time.sleep(0.1)
    except:
        self.is_finished = True
```

so as to gracefully exit the thread. However, I forgot to import time... :)